# HTML5 video low FPS / lagging?

Tags: html, video, frame-rate

Currently i'm having a background video for my website. The file is a .mp4 (1920x1080) format which is 25 seconds long (not a big file to be honest).

Here comes the tricky part.. the video runs all well, until I visit the website on a different computer (for example mac, using safari). Suddenly the video gets slown down and pixels can be count.

Effects are used inside of my video and may causes a higher bitrate. But whenever I watch the video on YouTube or whatever, it isn't lagging at all.

Does anyone know what could cause this?

P.S: I tested this on 2 different computers (a MAC book, which is pretty fast) and a slower computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert your video like that with the codec defined :

```
<video autoplay="true" loop="true"><source src="video/test4.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'></video>
```